# Displaying two Contact Numbers and Contact Name in a same row of custom list view

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me If a contact has 2 or more phone numbers how should I be able to put them in a single Row of list view. right now they are showing in different rows having same name how should I display the both phone numbers and the contact name in a same row of custom list view? The code is pasted below

```
    private ListView listView;
private List<ContactBean> list = new ArrayList<ContactBean>();

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {

        String name = phones
                .getString(phones
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

        String phoneNumber = phones
                .getString(phones
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        ContactBean objContact = new ContactBean();
        objContact.setName(name);
        objContact.setPhoneNo(phoneNumber);
        list.add(objContact);

    }
    phones.close();

    ContanctAdapter objAdapter = new ContanctAdapter(
            ContactListActivity.this, R.layout.alluser_row, list);
    listView.setAdapter(objAdapter);

    if (null != list && list.size() != 0) {
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<ContactBean>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(ContactBean lhs, ContactBean rhs) {
                return lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                ContactListActivity.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("");
```

And this is contact adpater class.

```
    public class ContanctAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactBean> {

private Activity activity;
private List<ContactBean> items;
private int row;
private ContactBean objBean;

public ContanctAdapter(Activity act, int row, List<ContactBean> items) {
    super(act, row, items);

    this.activity = act;
    this.row = row;
    this.items = items;

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    if ((items == null) || ((position + 1) > items.size()))
        return view;

    objBean = items.get(position);

    holder.tvname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
    holder.tvPhoneNo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvphone);

    if (holder.tvname != null && null != objBean.getName()
            && objBean.getName().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvname.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getName()));
    }
    if (holder.tvPhoneNo != null && null != objBean.getPhoneNo()
            && objBean.getPhoneNo().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvPhoneNo.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getPhoneNo()));
    }
    return view;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvname, tvPhoneNo;
}
```

}

and I get this result from the code but I want to show that if the contact has 2 or more number they must be shown in the same row under one name. but it is showing in a separate row . please help me !!!

[image: the output![enter image description here]

Comment: possible duplicate of [android : listview customization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597950/android-listview-customization)

Comment: just make a custom listitem layout, where you have a textview for name, a textview for first number and a textview for second number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Here if you want to display example 50 Contact no in 25 row then first set items.size()/2 in getcount here also check odd even sequence if 51 contact no present then 26 row needed so
if(items.size()%2==0){
size=items.size()/2;
else{
size=(items.size()/2)+1;
}

and then in every row take two textview for contact name and two textview for contact no and set it

objBean = items.get(position);
objBean2 = items.get(position+1);

textview1.settext(objBean.getName());
textview2.settext(objBean.getPhoneNo());

textview3.settext(objBean2.getName());
textview4.settext(objBean2.getPhoneNo());

thats it..
```

Comment: you are saying that I have to take four textviews for each row in other to meet my requirement ?

Comment: ok I did that but you know I have another problem now I don't know how to get the other number in the textview I wrote like this but it's giving the error and if I change it to number then both the numbers are same
String phoneNumber2 = phones
                .getString(phones
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME));

Comment: then get all contact no with its name and short it by name and then check name if name are same then it is second no of that person.